# How is the char variable able to store a string without using square brackets or curly braces and how does it iterate to the next character?

Tags: c

I am currently learning how recursion work by reversing a sentence and I can't seem to understand how the char variable is able to store a string without using square brackets or curly braces and how it iterates to the next character

I am new to this and I hope my question isn't too simple to ask

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_recursion();

int main() {

    printf("Input a sentence: ");
    swap_recursion();

    return 0;
}

void swap_recursion(){
    char sentence;

    scanf("%c", &sentence);
    if (sentence != '\n'){
        swap_recursion();
        printf("%c", sentence);

    }

}
```

Comment: The variable isn't storing a string, it stores just a single character. But if you print multiple characters, one by one after each other, it looks like a string.

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Then you can use it to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. That will hopefully help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Think of each recursive call as calling a brand new function which happens to execute the same code as `swap_recursion`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer @Some programmer dude, I will definitely check it out!

Comment: Each execution of each function gets its own set of local variables.  That includes recursive executions: when a function calls itself, the recursive execution does not share local variables with the calling execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is stored in multiple instances of `char sentence;` on the stack. Each recursive call of `swap_recursion()` makes a new `char sentence;` on the stack, and stores one character from the input there. The stack keeps building up until a new line is encountered. At that point, the entire string is stored on the stack. Then each character is printed in the reverse order they were read, by unrolling the stack with each return.

Comment: So because I inputted a string to a function that takes one character, the scanf() will take build up the stack until the new line is encountered. Since it stopped just before the new line, it will print out in reverse order. Is that right?

Comment: @Snowie `scanf` will not build up the stack. Each recursive call to `swap_recursion` takes a piece of the the stack and places a unique instance of `sentence` in that part of the stack.